# How to solve a linear program with temporal dimension?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have an optimization problem where I need to make sure that the optimal solution remains as is as long as possible along a given timespan say [t0, t1000] for the sake of simplicity.

The core of my mathematical model makes use of both the assignment problem and multi commodity flow problem. The problem asks for making sure that the assignment of jobs/tasks (or at a high level of abstraction entities) and flows (communication) between them remains optimal and does not violate some constraints including the flow conservation constraint.

How do we usually solve this type of optimization problems which includes time as a parameter ?

Comment: It depends. There are many different ways this is done depending on the situation.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, could you elaborate a bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of solving such a problem - although your description is not very specific - is to discretize the time component. This can make the problem pretty large since you are practically multiplying your model. You would then track the changes between one time step and the next and try to minimize that.

Comment: I have edited the question. Could you elaborate a bit more on your comment ? Do you suggest if I am practically multiplying model and as the problem is NP-Hard to turn to model predictive control techniques as I am dealing with dynamic system ?